# Number of distinct values of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

In this I could not understand that after third step how they have concluded there are 5 distinct values .

Comment: You can draw a picture of the unit circle and mark the angles $8r\pi/5$, $r=1,2,3\ldots,20$ to see why there are $5$ such points.

Comment: @JonasMeyer okay thanks  , I got it

Answer (score -3, accepted):

HINT: You are looking at a complex number with 5 roots. Draw a circle in Argard Plane and correlate with the concept of $n^{th}$ roots of unity.